# Sightseeing the USA by air

Tags: air-travel, usa, sightseeing, tours

The next time family from overseas comes to visit me in the USA, I would like for them to see the major sites in the USA.

Is there such a thing as a prepaid flying tour of the USA?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are/were looking for. If you mean a flight that lets them see the major sites from the air, that doesn't seem feasible: the USA is a huge country and a direct flight from New York to Los Angeles takes more than six hours. So do you mean some kind of organized tour that visits multiple cities (on the ground) and gets between them by flying? Again, the USA is a huge country and there are so many places to see that "see[ing] the major sites" would take months.

Answer (score 7):

> UPDATE: the link I gave previously no longer works, but these two do:
>
> - [SkyTeam](https://www.skyteam.com/en/flights-and-destinations/travel-passes/go-usa-and-canada/)
> - [OneWorld](https://www.oneworld.com/flights/single-continent-fares/visit-north-america)

<del>This listing should get you started: http://www.airtimetable.com/airpass_north_America.htm</del>

Comment: Your link seems to be down for now

Comment: Updated with new links.