# Are there still any “Fly as much as you like” air passes for the U.S.?

Tags: air-travel, usa, airlines, tickets

Back in 1993 I had a ticket called 'Delta Air Lines Travel America Standby Airpass' that allowed me to take an unlimited number of flights on Delta Airlines within a 30 day period. 60 days were available as well.

There were some conditions:

- You had to purchase the pass along with a transatlantic flight
  (possibly other long distance flights into the U.S. worked as well
  and they did not necessarily had to be with the same airline)
- You could not be a resident of the U.S. or Canada
- You could only use flights within the continental U.S.
- Your seat was not guaranteed, when showing up at the airport you
  would get added to the bottom of the stand-by passengers list, but
  most of the time, this was not a problem.

I know that at the time other airlines besides Delta had the same kind of passes, but do they still exist today?

It seems today air passes work differently, you have to buy coupons for a predefined route. The price depends on the distance and number of flights. An example is the [Star Alliance North America Airpass](http://www.staralliance.com/en/fares/regional-fares/north-america-airpass/)

That's not what I am looking for, I like the unlimited 'Fly as much as you can' pass.

If there is a positive answer to this, it may also be a good answer to the question ['Sightseeing the USA by air'](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/31/1317)

Comment: Something even cooler that most definitely does not exist anymore are *lifetime* "fly as much as you like" passes: http://articles.latimes.com/2012/may/05/business/la-fi-0506-golden-ticket-20120506

Comment: Crandall was a visionary. Many Airlines also offered lifetime discounts to long serving employees, and many countries give politicians benefits that come close. I did a "see america" on Northwest, and was fed every second day in flight. As an aside bus companies did similar deals.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

These types of passes have not existed for many years.

JetBlue has run an "All You Can Jet" deal on a few occasions over the past few years, but it's only been run for specific dates rates (ie, not any 30 days you want) and is fairly restrictive.

The odds of anyone bringing back something like you've described is fairly low due to the current state of US air travel.  "Standby" travel (in the form you've described) is basically non-existent now days due to reduced numbers of flights resulting in much higher "loads" than in past years.  For some specific routes - especially those between hubs - you could be waiting days or (at some times of year) even weeks to get a standby seat on a flight.

As you've stated, "Air Passes" are the current equivalent of what you're describing, but they are priced based on segments and distance - not an "all-you-can-eat" type of deal. Star Alliance (United, Continental, US Air), OneWorld (American Airlines), SkyTeam (Delta), Alaska Airlines and others all has some form of Air Pass program - normally only available to non-US residents when bought in conjunction with an airfare to the US.

Comment: I don't know that it's really correct to say that there are a 'reduced number of flights' within the U.S. now. It would be more correct to say that capacity has not been growing as quickly as demand.

Comment: The inexistence is independent of the low state of current US air travel. Modern technology and booking mechanisms, together with larger networks and code-sharing have led to a secular increase in loads. In other words, it is caused by a good phenomenon (from business perspective), not a bad one. I agree that you conclude the high load ratio too, I just doubt it is caused by recent decline in demand.

Comment: @FooBar What do you mean by "secular" here? The only meaning I'm aware of is "not sacred," which doesn't seem to make sense.

Comment: @phoog http://www.investopedia.com/terms/s/secular.asp = long-term contrast with cyclical = short-term

Answer (score 6):

The best I can find on the subject is this:

http://seattletimes.nwsource.com/html/travel/2015386729_webairfare21.html

As far as I can tell the JetBlue has actually ended that program not so long ago but it may come back:

http://www.jetblue.com/aycj/

Answer (score 4):

Since the last this question was answered there is an update.

Company called [OneGo](http://www.onego.com) offers unlimited flights as a monthly subscription depending on where you fly and how often.

Plans pricing can be found [here](https://www.onego.com/pricing-and-regions/) but they start about $1500/month for regional plans.

I think it offers more benefit for business travelers but you may take advantage of it if you plan on travelling the US for awhile.

Comment: The OneGo site is down now, I think it doesn't exist any more.