# Is there an airline ticket like a bus pass with unlimited trips?

Tags: air-travel, tickets, airlines, loyalty-programs

I travel to Sweden from The UK twice a year and it would be good to have an airplane pass for 10 years for example. To clarify I'd like to buy a ticket that allows me to travel on unlimited journeys via airplane from UK to Sweden for the period of 10 years.

Comment: Just a reminder: From the tour: _This site is all about getting answers. It's not a discussion forum. There's no chit-chat_. **and** _Use comments to ask for more information or clarify a question or answer_.

Comment: Related (but not duplicate): [Are there still any “Fly as much as you like” air passes for the U.S.?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/4459/are-there-still-any-fly-as-much-as-you-like-air-passes-for-the-u-s?rq=1)

Comment: The price of a 10 year ticket puts you fairly well into the turbofan range.

Comment: Bus passes tend to be subsidized by local governments, as they lose money big time.  They do provide benefits of less traffic, more workforce, etc, so most people are ok with their taxes being used thusly.  But as a taxpayer I wouldn't want to subsidize your flights to the UK, that is your bosses responsibility.

Comment: Forgive me, but "twice a year" is not frequent enough to even consider such a thing: neither for you nor the airline. Airlines do have corporate discounts for regular travellers, but, it is for people doing these commutes *twice a day* (mostly pharmaceuticals employees). Just look around for the cheapest prices when you need to travel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not really. There used to be one with American Airlines.  There's a reason they can't do it though, and it's people like [this guy, who clocked up 21 million dollars worth of flights](http://nypost.com/2012/05/13/freequent-flier-has-wings-clipped-after-american-airlines-takes-away-his-unlimited-pass/).  He'd fly to another country just for lunch, because he could.  In today's air travel climate, you need to make some money on each seat, it's getting harder and harder to do with the competitive industry that it is.

Jetblue tried it in 2009. [They've since cancelled it](http://www.budgettravel.com/blog/jetblue-offers-an-all-you-can-fly-pass,10758/).

At least, that was the answer a year or so ago.  Suddenly, a couple of incidents have changed this.

- [Air Asia is offering an unlimited monthly travel chance in SE Asia](http://www.pointswithacrew.com/airasia-offering-unlimited-southeast-asia-travel-pass/).  There are lots of conditions, however.
- And now just two months ago [OneGo](http://roadwarriorvoices.com/2015/06/23/startup-offers-unlimited-flights-on-commerical-airlines-for-1500-a-month-plus-free-checked-bags-precheck-and-wi-fi/) is attempting to be a startup offering unlimited flights for $1500 a month plus free checked bags precheck and wifi.  However, if you're a semi-frequent business flyer you could clock that up pretty fast, so it'll be interesting to see how long they last.

However, aside from these occasional anomalies, there's really no such thing any longer.  It's too expensive, and too risky for the airlines to do, aside from perhaps as a promotional (short-lived) endeavour.

Comment: It was fun reading the article about that man! Shame they took it away from him :D

Comment: OneGo's "unlimited" actually has a few significant limitations.  Without paying substantial up-charges you're limited to booking at least 7 days in advance and only having 4 segments booked at any one time.  With those limitations in place, while the heaviest fliers probably still will be able to save money on the deal it might be viable over the long term depending on how many people they get to sign up for convenience even if they don't average $18k/year in flights.